# python how to skip an element when slice a list

Tags: python, list, slice

I want to get [[1,2,4], [11, 12, 14], [21, 22, 24]] from [[1,2,3,4], [11, 12, 13, 14], [21, 22, 23, 24]]. 
What is an elegant way?

My real problem is a 100000*17 2d list. Thanks.

Comment: You want to remove a column?

Comment: You should seriously consider [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/).

Comment: You should also consider [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), especially if your data is not just simply numbers.

Answer (score 3):

One way is:

```
import numpy as np
np.array(lst)[:, (0, 1, 3)]
```

Comment: and you can later change it to `lst = list(np.array(lst)[:, (0, 1, 3)])` if you want to use it as a python list.

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward way is:

```
rows = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [11, 12, 13, 14], [21, 22, 23, 24]]

print([[a, b, d] for a, b, c, d in rows])
```

or

```
print([[row[0], row[1], row[3]] for row in rows])
```

Comment: Elegant, efficient list comprehension to remove the nth element from a list of lists. I prefer this method over pop() method on the lists because the original list is intact afterward.

Comment: Thank you! This is the most primitive way i can find, but I do not know if it is as efficient as using `np`. @Ron Norris

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to pop the index of the element for each sub-list:

```
>>my_list =  [[1,2,3,4], [11, 12, 13, 14], [21, 22, 23, 24]]
```

`>>for i in my_list:`

```
>>    i.pop(2)

>> 3
>> 13
>> 23
>> print my_list
>> [[1, 2, 4], [11, 12, 14], [21, 22, 24]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use unpacking in Python3:

```
s = [[1,2,3,4], [11, 12, 13, 14], [21, 22, 23, 24]]
new_s = [a+[b] for *a, _, b in s]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 4], [11, 12, 14], [21, 22, 24]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]])
print(arr[:, (0,1,3,4)])
```

Output
[[ 1  2  4  5]
[ 6  7  9 10]]